# Combining solar system planets orbits and positions in Graphics3D and Show

Tags: graphics3d, animation, curated-data, astronomy

I am building an animated model of the solar system, where I would like to display the `OrbitPath`s of the planets along with their `Position`s at any one point in time. I would like to display the orbital paths as lines, just as they are given when inputting `AstronomicalData["Earth", "OrbitPath"]`.

I'd like to display the positions as `Sphere`s though. For some reason, even though I am combining the two graphical elements, only the spheres are displaying, and I cannot see the orbit lines at all. Would anyone be able to pinpoint what I am doing wrong in my code?

```
Animate[
 Show[
  Graphics3D[
   AstronomicalData[#, "OrbitPath"] & /@ AstronomicalData["Planet"]], 
  Graphics3D[
   Sphere[AstronomicalData[#, {"Position", DateList[x][[;; 3]]}] & /@ 
     AstronomicalData["Planet"], 5*10^10]]
  ], {x, 1, 10000000000}, AnimationRate -> 100000000
 ]
```

For the record, I tried putting the graphics primitives in a single `Graphics3D` and combining the spheres and lines into a single list of primitives, but that was throwing up too many problems so I figured this way would be more straightforward.

Comment: If  you study the output of `AstronomicalData["Venus", "OrbitPath"]` and compare it to the output of `AstronomicalData["Venus", "Position"]` you'll see that the former doesn't provide the actual path coordinates but some kind of scaled version with numbers differing orders  of magnitude from the latter ones.

Comment: Thank you, @SjoerdC.deVries. I didn't realise that. Do you have a quick solution for how to scale them up to the position coordinate system?

Comment: It looks like the scaling is in astronomical units, so a multiplication by 149597870700 should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The orbit path is given in astronomical units whereas the position is given in meters, so you have to scale:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], "m"]
(* Quantity[149597870700, "Meters"] *)

Animate[
 Graphics3D[
  {
   (AstronomicalData[#, "OrbitPath"] /.Line[a__] :> Line[149597870700 a]) & /@ 
          AstronomicalData["Planet"], 
   Sphere[AstronomicalData[#, {"Position", DateList[x][[;; 3]]}] & /@ 
     AstronomicalData["Planet"], 5*10^10]
   }
  ], {x, 1, 10000000000}, AnimationRate -> 100000000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I keep getting $Aborted when running the code. V 9.01 on windows 7.![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GqDc0.png) restarted kernel few times. did not make difference. May be it is internet issue reading the data from WRI server

Comment: @nasser Just start some AstronomicalData stuff on their own, like `AstronomicalData["Venus", "OrbitPath"]` to load the Paclet data and only then evaluate the `Animation`

Comment: Perfect, @SjoerdC.deVries. This is precisely the answer I was looking for. Thank you. For me it also aborts a few times before running properly, but it looks like this might just be the sheer quantity of data it is calling up from `AstronomicalData`?